# How SSH works with GiHub or BitBucket

Tags: github, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

All,

I am using SSH to talk to github/bitbucket, sometimes it works, but sometimes it just failed left me with no clue. When trying to figure out the problem, I realize I actually not quite clear about how this works:

1. How the private key is selected?
   We could use ssh-add or pageant to load private keys, but mulitple keys could be loaded - how ssh client decide which private key to use when I receive a challenge after sending the request?
2. How the public key is selected?
   There are tons of public keys on GitHub server, when I send a request to github (like git push), I don't remember I need to specify my username that registered on GitHub(we do need to config the user.name, but I think that is only for tag your commits) -so how GitHub figure out which public key to use when receive a request, and even GitHub knows which user is sending the request(how?), how could it select the right public key from multiple keys - remember I could add more than 1 keys to my account.

Thanks.

Comment: Give more information as to when your failures happen, though that should probably be in another question, rather than a How question, you also ask a "why" question here, and it is confusing as to which you really want an answer to.  If you would like help in figuring out why it is that sometimes you can connect and sometimes you can't, you will need to provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ~/.ssh/id_rsa file is selected by default.

If you need to provide another key, you can use the IdentityFile directive in your `~/.ssh/config` file.

Github knows which account simply because when challenged, your system provides a username as part of your key challenge sequence, and a lookup is done.  The keys are then exchanged, and either validated or rejected.

I would suggest having the [man pages](http://openssh.com/manual.html) at your disposal.  Here is a good reference for the [OpenSSH project](http://openssh.com/manual.html), with a lot more information about how this works in a general sense.

Github has modified their ssh daemon for their needs, but mostly, they must follow the specifications, and so externally, we won't see a difference in behavior, though we get the benefit of being able to connect to the service quickly as authenticated/authorized for whatever actions we are allowed to perform on the repositories.